# LWIP - udp_new function always returns NULL

Tags: c, stm32, lwip

I am trying to create a DHCP Server using lwip on an STM32F767ZI. I am adapting the implemention from [here](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/lwip/apps/dhcpserver/dhcpserver.c), but I have trouble with the udp_new function - always returns NULL.

```
    /**
 * @ingroup udp_raw
 * Creates a new UDP pcb which can be used for UDP communication. The
 * pcb is not active until it has either been bound to a local address
 * or connected to a remote address.
 *
 * @return The UDP PCB which was created. NULL if the PCB data structure
 * could not be allocated.
 *
 * @see udp_remove()
 */
struct udp_pcb *
udp_new(void)
{
  struct udp_pcb *pcb;

  LWIP_ASSERT_CORE_LOCKED();

  pcb = (struct udp_pcb *)memp_malloc(MEMP_UDP_PCB);
  /* could allocate UDP PCB? */
  if (pcb != NULL) {
    /* UDP Lite: by initializing to all zeroes, chksum_len is set to 0
     * which means checksum is generated over the whole datagram per default
     * (recommended as default by RFC 3828). */
    /* initialize PCB to all zeroes */
    memset(pcb, 0, sizeof(struct udp_pcb));
    pcb->ttl = UDP_TTL;
#if LWIP_MULTICAST_TX_OPTIONS
    udp_set_multicast_ttl(pcb, UDP_TTL);
#endif /* LWIP_MULTICAST_TX_OPTIONS */
  }
  return pcb;
}
```

This is the udp_new function and the main problem is the memp_malloc.
I did not find any concrete solution on google, but when I changed memp_malloc with just "malloc" the memory was allocated but the program did not worked as expected.

Why does the memp_malloc function is not working properly?

Comment: Check the value of MEMP_NUM_UDP_PCB in lwipopts.h is more than zero.

Comment: it is 5, checked it right now